# Setup l2tp using Strongswan

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, l2tp, xl2tpd, ikev1

I setup ikev2 using Strongswan, Now I need to add l2tp support to that
What is the best and easy method to add l2tp support to Strongswan?
Appreciate for any help

Answer (score 0):

As for strongSwan configuration, you only need to allow encapsulation of L2TP traffic into the tunnel. To do so you should specify L2TP port in `local_ts/remote_ts` parameters in `swanctl.conf` or `leftsubnet/rightsubnet` in `ipsec.conf`. Default port for L2TP is `UDP/1701`.
For example:

```
> cat swanctl.conf
connections {
    # some params
    connection1 {
    # some params
        children {
            child1 {
                # some params
                local_ts = 192.168.1.1[udp/1701]
                remote_ts = 192.168.1.10[udp/1701]
                # maybe some more params
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After establishing IPsec tunnel you should run your L2TP server/client as if there is no IPsec tunnel at all. Your L2TP traffic will be transparently encrypted on one side end decrypted on another side.
I'd recommend [this](https://www.elastichosts.com/blog/linux-l2tpipsec-vpn-client/) article on configuring L2TP in xl2tpd.

Answer (score 0):

Working swanctl config of strongswan in client mode when connecting to a L2TP VPN hub with PSK:

```
connections {
    vpnhub {
        local-1 {
            id=192.168.1.27
            auth=psk
        }
        remote-1 {
            id=325.678.571.25
            auth=psk
        }
        children {
            default {
                esp_proposals=aes128-sha1-modp1024
                dpd_action=clear
                start_action=trap
                mode=transport
                local_ts=dynamic[17/1701]
                remote_ts=dynamic[17/1701]
            }
        }
        version=2
        proposals=aes128-sha1-modp2048
        local_addrs=192.168.1.27
        remote_addrs=325.678.571.25
        rekey_time=1h
    }
}
```